# How to extract parts of a partially patterned line in a text file in Python?

Tags: python, file, text, extract

I have a text file with the following content:

```
0:00 txt txt e-mail1_to_extract txt_to_extract1 txt txt /data
0:00 txt txt e-mail2_to_extract txt_to_extract2 txt txt /data
0:00 txt txt txt e-mail3_to_extract txt_to_extract3 txt txt /var
0:00 txt txt txt txt e-mail4_to_extract txt_to_extract4 txt txt /var
0:00 txt txt e-mail5_to_extract txt_to_extract5 txt txt /data
```

First, I'd like to extract all these lines between "0:00" and "/data" or "/var". Second, I'd like to handle this data so that I can extract only two parts of it. The text contained in this already extracted range is not standardized, so I can't use something like "startwith"/"endwith", however, the entire text is joined (like a whole word) and its positions are always repeated after the email part. Is there any way to specifically map that part and extract the email + the next string?

Txt = extra text that I don't want to extract.

I've already tried to start with the code below but didn't get any results:

```
with open('content.txt') as infile, open('extraction.txt', 'w') as outfile:
copy = False
for line in infile:
    if line.strip() == "0:00":
        copy = True
        continue
    elif line.strip() == "/":
        copy = False
        continue
    elif copy:
        outfile.write(line)
```

Desired output:

```
e-mail1_to_extract txt_to_extract1
e-mail2_to_extract txt_to_extract2
e-mail3_to_extract txt_to_extract3
e-mail4_to_extract txt_to_extract4
e-mail5_to_extract txt_to_extract5
```

Thank you!

Comment: It might be easier to simply parse those pieces out with regex especially if you know the `0:00` starts the line, and the path ends it.

Comment: Please provide your desired output for the example you provided so we can help better. Thank you

Comment: Done, Ehsan! :D

Answer (score 0):

I used a sample file in format you provided -

```
0:00 txt txt123 abc@abs.com txt_to_extract1 txt6456 txtssss /data
0:00 txt11 txt111 abd@rtx.vg txt_to_extract2 txtssss txtffff /data
0:00 txt111 txt123 txt tyrr@rgahb.com txt_to_extract3 txtosvbsvs txtkkkk /var
0:00 txt456 txt3663 srsr31415s@gagha.gha txt e-mail4_to_extract txt_to_extract4 txabjahsjat txtasba /var
0:00 txtGJK txtfggg gfa456vaj@aghaha.com txt_to_extract5 txtbxajla txtzbaza /data
```

I used the following code (function to determine email, please change regex accordingly) -

```
import re 
  
regex = '^[a-z0-9]+[\._]?[a-z0-9]+[@]\w+[.]\w{2,3}$'
def check(email):    
    if(re.search(regex,email)):  
        return True
    else:  
        return False
        
def getcols(row):
    for i in row.keys():
        if check(row[i]):
            return str(row[i]) + " " + str(row[i+1])
        else:
            return ""


ls = []
with open('TestData.txt') as infile, open('extraction.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        ls = line.split()
        for i in range(len(ls)):
            if check(ls[i]):
                try:
                    outfile.write(ls[i] + " " + ls[i+1]+"\n")
                except:
                    pass
```

I get the following output -

```
abc@abs.com txt_to_extract1
abd@rtx.vg txt_to_extract2
tyrr@rgahb.com txt_to_extract3
srsr31415s@gagha.gha txt
gfa456vaj@aghaha.com txt_to_extract5
```

Comment: @ronphan if answer works for you, please accept the answer